# Replace a space and three periods with just three periods using regex preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

Trying to get this to work, but my regex is rusty and nothing I'm googling seems to be working

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/\s+/u", '...', $post->getPostExcerpt(12)) ?>
```

This does replace all spaces with a ... but what I'm trying to do is replace a space and three dots with just three dots.

I tried str_replace and it didn't pick up the space so I'm trying to get it with preg_replace.

```
/\s+/u+(...)
```

The above just replaces every character with dots.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you have an exact string to replace why do you want to use regEx at all? You can just string replace ' ...' with '...'

Comment: What string are you using it on, and what is the expected output?

Comment: Try `preg_replace("/\s+\.\.\./u", '...', $post->getPostExcerpt(12))`

Comment: regex: `\s(\.{3})`; replacement: `$1`

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/\s\.{3}/u", '...', $post->getPostExcerpt(12)) ?>
```

https://regex101.com/r/1KXvs9/2

or just

```
str_replace(" ...","...",$post->getPostExcerpt(12));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex for this simple replace.  This replaces `space...` with `...`:

```
echo str_replace(' ...', '...', $post->getPostExcerpt(12));
```

With regex you could use:

```
echo preg_replace('/ [.]{3}/', '...', $post->getPostExcerpt(12));
```

Comment: Does the `[.]` within the Square Brackets not need escaping like - `[\.]`? An honest Curiosity...

Comment: @Poiz: No it does not because within `[]` it is seen as a period/dot and not the special match any character character.

Comment: inside `[.]` it treats that as literal `.`

Comment: The str_replace didn't work for this type of space that was being generated for some reason, that's why I couldn't do it the first way,

Comment: Well, then it's not a space as stated in the question.  Maybe its an entity `&nbsp;`?  If so, then use that.

Comment: View the source of the page to see.

Comment: Oddly the source of the page just showed a space, but nothing would target the space except this... `preg_replace("(\s+\.{3})", '...', $post->getPostExcerpt(12)`

Comment: So there is more than 1 space

Answer (score 0):

what I'm trying to do is replace `a space` **and** `three dots` with just `three dots`.

```
$search = " ...";
$replace= '...';
print str_replace($search, $replace, $post->getPostExcerpt(12));
```

OR

```
$re = '/\s\.{3}/u';
$str = $post->getPostExcerpt(12);
$subst = '...';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

See regex : https://regex101.com/r/paAg7h/2

Comment: Not maybe `$search=" ..."`? Or do you mean you want to replace " ..." By the Asqii character '...' ?

Comment: @derHugo, yes your are right, I just unconsciously thought about OR not AND. thanks for pointing me out.:)

Comment: The 2nd one works. I put in my original posting that str_replace wasn't detecting it for some reason.